# Checking textbox for values in code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm perplexed about something in my code here and hoping that someone can clue me in here.

I am trying to check to see if my user has populated a textbox before I write data out to a record so I'm using this code below to check to see if the text box is populated or not. But this 'always' comes back as true and proceeds as if the user has placed text in the even if there is none.

```
if (ReasonTextBox.Text.ToString() != null)
   {
    //Some commands to write data to a table
   }
 else
   {
     //Some alternative things to do
   }
```

I've also done this without the ".ToString()" with the same results. As I've observed it in debug with or without text in the Textbox the code will step into the procedure regardless.

Soooooo... Being that I am fairly new to writing web sites in C# I must be missing something here apparently a blank textbox isn't really null? If that is the case, how would you suggest I go about checking for it being populated or not?

Comment: Try using something like `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(string))`

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property is not null, it contains an empty string.

Try instead:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReasonTextBox.Text)) {
    // do something
}
```

If `Text` had been null, you would have got a `NullReferenceException` when calling the `ToString()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `string` that afaik is never `null`. (Otherwise you would get a `NullReferenceException` when calling `ToString()`).

The call to `ToString()` is obsolete as `Text` already is a `string`.

You don't want to check if `Text` is `null` but if it's *empty*:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReasonTextBox.Text))
```

or if a string containing only whitespaces is a wrong input too:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReasonTextBox.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay going to end this before it begins. For anyone that runs across this let me explain the background of what I discovered and how I resolved this.

In addition to the asp:TextBox I was using a ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender on top of the textbox as well. Now I'm not certain and don't have the time to go back and verify, but I'm highly suspect that the issue is that the extender added what I found was a 
 in the textbox. The 
 of course isn't visible to the necked eye in the rendered page and wasn't until I build my stored procedure to work around the problem and wrote the data to the table and saw the 
 (which I was assuming would be blank or null) that I realized what was going on.  So all I did was simply wrote a secondary check after this to check for a 
 value in the textbox and if 'only a 
' avoid the write. This fixed the issue.  A bit like an HP calculator solution but works well!